# How to get accurate time from start to end

Tags: mysql, sql

I have durations times table which have two columns sd_time (start time) and sd_etime (end time)
i want to select all times which not start and end between (11:30 - 12:05)
so if sd_stime = 12:00 and sd_etime = 1:00 it will returned
but if it st_stime = 11:00 and sd_eitme = 12:00 it will not returned

```
SELECT * 
FROM d_services_type_durations dsd 
FROM d_services_type_durations dsd 
WHERE (dsd.sd_stime <= '11:30' OR dsd.sd_stime >= '12:05')
      AND
      (dsd.sd_etime <= '11:30' OR dsd.sd_etime >= '12:05')
```

and this is the schema 
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55f09/20

Comment: You say you want *select all times which not start and end between (11:30 - 12:05)*. So you want both start **and** end time to lie outside this interval, or either of these?

Comment: i want to return also from 11:00 to 12:00

Comment: Check my answer, it may return the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM d_services_type_durations dsd 
WHERE dsd.sd_stime < '11:30' OR dsd.sd_stime > '12:05'
      OR
      dsd.sd_etime < '11:30' OR dsd.sd_etime > '12:05'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55f09/3)

Comment: thanks MR giorgos but this code dot return 10:55 to 11:30

Comment: @user1080247 I think not. Have you seen the demo? Row 10:55 to 11:30 is there in the output (its the one with sd_id = 6)..

Comment: sorry you are right but when i add this condition dsd.sd_st_id = 2 i see all times not only that have this id

Comment: @user1080247 Can you setup an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: if you see here it returned 12:00 to 1:00 and this between 11:30 to 12:05

Comment: @user1080247 You have `sd_st_id = 2` **not** `sd_id = 2`

Comment: yes i want to filter by sd_st_id and i see  it returned 12:00 to 1:00 and this between 11:30 to 12:05

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104188/discussion-between-giorgos-betsos-and-user1080247).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    d_services_type_durations AS dsd 
WHERE 
    (dsd.sd_stime > '00:00' AND dsd.sd_stime < '11:30' AND dsd.sd_etime > '00:00' AND dsd.sd_etime < '11:30')
    OR (dsd.sd_stime > '12:05' AND dsd.sd_stime < '23:59' AND dsd.sd_etime > '12:05' AND dsd.sd_etime < '23:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the STR_TO_DATE function

```
SELECT * FROM d_services_type_durations dsd WHERE 
  dsd.sd_stime <> '11:30' 
 AND 
  STR_TO_DATE(dsd.sd_stime, "%k:%i") <= STR_TO_DATE('12:05', "%k:%i")
 AND 
  STR_TO_DATE(dsd.sd_etime, "%k:%i") <= STR_TO_DATE('11:30', "%k:%i") 
 AND
   STR_TO_DATE(dsd.sd_etime, "%k:%i") <= STR_TO_DATE('12:05', "%k:%i")
```

The main problem is that you are using a type varchar that doesnt handle well this kind of comparisions. Instead of using this solution, converting everything to datetime, I recommend you to change the type in the schema